# More secure option than DDNS + port forwarding to host website

Tags: networking, ssh, security, webserver

I wondered if there is a more secure solution for my setup. A small PC at home is hosting a website (on port 8080) while my router is forwarding outside requests from port 80 to internal port 8080 of this PC. A free DDNS (DuckDNS) also tracks my IP address, so that I can simply use my set address from anywhere.

Does this pose any serious security issues? There are also other ports opened (VNC, SSH) and I am not sure, if that's a bad thing or not. The website of that PC does not (yet?) contain any private information and it's rather a small project for fun than anything serious. Nevertheless, I might expand its usage if anything comes to mind.
Is there a more secure option? I can see my external IP address when using the DuckDNS address.

Comment: Are those "other ports" open for external access, or only internal?

Comment: Why do you have those other services running?

Comment: Those ports are visible outside for HTTP, SSH VNC and MS Remote Desktop. (all coming from the mentioned PC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide your IP address when using DDNS - you can't
hide it at all if you wish your computer to be reachable via DNS.
If your ISP changes your IP address when the router is turned off
for some time, this is the only tiny protection you can have from
DDNS.

But it's unlikely that anyone will randomly happen upon your
DNS name, especially if it's long enough.
Most hackers will just simply scan the entire internet to find
computers with open ports, so will not bother with DNS.

Note that the port 8080 is a bad choice, since it's very popular
for web servers, so most hackers will also test for it.
The best protection is to use some random number that relates to
nothing.

Your router may have a firewall that can selectively allow
through connections on the ports from specified outside
sources, according to some rules, so check it out.
This would be your best protection.

Comment: Thank you. The visible ports for outside are 443, 22, 80, 5900 - 5910 and 3389. Wouldn't you need a password for accessing any of these? Or are they easy to brute force because of no limit of attempts?
Note that port 8080 is NOT open for outside, but 80.

Comment: These are well-known port numbers that will be tested for exactly the applications that will be answering, so very unsafe. You can use for them any port that you like in the router, since port-forwarding can direct them to the right ports on the computer.

Comment: Would SSH still work than? The protocol is port 22 and thus would always connect to my myipaddress:22 ,right?
Same for port 80. I don't think DuckDNS would in this case still work if I used port 2351 (or any other).

Comment: It depends on the SSH client whether it can use another port to access the router from the outside, but the server behind the router can stay on the standard ports since the router will port-forward to them. I don't know DuckDNS and cannot answer, but from experience with a similar product it usually connects to its server by its IP address so is not affected by the router's firewall and doesn't need port-forwarding.